# how to managing hibernate session in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, hibernate-session

i have problem with session close what impact during running this application and what if this goes in production.

i faceting two problem in my production server its consume lots off memory during application usage around 800MB to just start up.

after some time its give an outofmemory error and server crashes

i am using tomcat server for deploy my application

my code is this

```
@Transactional
public Collection list(String queryString, Object[] value) throws Exception {
  Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
  return query.list();
}

@Transactional
public Collection list(String queryString, Object[] value) throws Exception {
  Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
  Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
  return query.list();
}
```

if i do close the session then lazy initialization gives an error for session is already closed.

please help me to come out this problem.
How we can take care about open session in hibernate with spring configuration
i am using hibernate 3.6.1 and spring 3.0.6.

Comment: what kind of application your are working ??

Comment: And I don't think you need to open the session once you are using @Transactional

Comment: That depends. If you want to access lazy loaded references after the method call you will need an open session else the session will be closed right after the transaction. However the actual transactional boundary should be the service and not the dao layer.

Comment: Yes agree with you M. Deinum, for lazy loading we can also use the OpenSessionInView filter.

Comment: but why its take too much memory to load application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add VM arguments to your server to avoid outofmemory error

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

and add

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

code above method to strictly handle transaction without worry about Session  object